# Cakepdf PageSize

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf

Im trying to set a custom size in cm or mm, but it isn't working. I cant find an example that let me see how to do it.

I have tried with this code but with no success

```
Configure::write('CakePdf', array(
        'engine' => 'CakePdf.DomPdf',
        'options' => array(
            'print-media-type' => false,
            'outline' => true,
            'dpi' => 96
        ),
        'margin' => array(
            'bottom' => 15,
            'left' => 50,
            'right' => 30,
            'top' => 45
        ),
        'orientation' => 'Portrait',
        'download' => false,
        'pageSize' => '2cm 2cm'
    ));
```

If I write 'pageSize' => 'LETTER', that works.. but i need a custom size.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

What pdf engine are you using?

If wkhtmltopdf, here is a list of supported based on https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/src/lib/pdfsettings.cc

```
DLL_LOCAL QMap<QString, QPrinter::PageSize> pageSizeMap() {
QMap<QString, QPrinter::PageSize> res;
res["A0"] = QPrinter::A0;
res["A1"] = QPrinter::A1;
res["A2"] = QPrinter::A2;
res["A3"] = QPrinter::A3;
res["A4"] = QPrinter::A4;
res["A5"] = QPrinter::A5;
res["A6"] = QPrinter::A6;
res["A7"] = QPrinter::A7;
res["A8"] = QPrinter::A8;
res["A9"] = QPrinter::A9;
res["B0"] = QPrinter::B0;
res["B1"] = QPrinter::B1;
res["B10"] = QPrinter::B10;
res["B2"] = QPrinter::B2;
res["B3"] = QPrinter::B3;
res["B4"] = QPrinter::B4;
res["B5"] = QPrinter::B5;
res["B6"] = QPrinter::B6;
res["B7"] = QPrinter::B7;
res["B8"] = QPrinter::B8;
res["B9"] = QPrinter::B9;
res["C5E"] = QPrinter::C5E;
res["Comm10E"] = QPrinter::Comm10E;
res["DLE"] = QPrinter::DLE;
res["Executive"] = QPrinter::Executive;
res["Folio"] = QPrinter::Folio;
res["Ledger"] = QPrinter::Ledger;
res["Legal"] = QPrinter::Legal;
res["Letter"] = QPrinter::Letter;
res["Tabloid"] = QPrinter::Tabloid;
return res;
```

}

Make sure you are using the correct uppercase and lowercase. 
Hope this helps. You and others who have the same problem. :D

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realised you're using DomPdf. I dont find any documentation for DomPDF. Perhaps you can first try adjusting the case. But I will edit my answer if I find something